# Loading data in details modal using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, modal-dialog

I'm trying to load data into modal using AngularJS. I did the load the data into a list of "cards" and it works fine. But, to each card, I need to open a details modal and to load the rest of the data within it. Follow my code:

//Part of index.html

```
<body ng-controller="CardsController">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="cards" ng-repeat="card in cards">
      <h3>{{card.user}}</h3>
      <button type="button" name="play" title="play" ng-click="toggleModal(card)">Play</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <my-modal show='modalShown' width='250px' height='40%'>
    <h3>{{card.user}}</h3> <-- here is my problem!
  </my-modal>
```

// js/controllers/cards-controller.js

```
angular.module('angstudy').controller('CardsController', function($scope,     $http){
  $scope.cards = [];

  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/persons')
  .success(function(retorno){
      console.log(retorno);
  $scope.cards = retorno;
  })
  .error(function(erro) {
      console.log(erro);
  });


  $scope.modalShown = false;

  $scope.toggleModal = function(card) {
    $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
  };
});
```

// js/directives/modal-dialog.js

```
angular.module('modalDialog', [])
.directive('myModal', function() {
  var ddo = {};

    ddo.restrict = "E";
    ddo.transclude = true;

    ddo.scope = {
        user: '@user',
        show: '='
    };

    ddo.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (attrs.width)
        scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
      if (attrs.height)
        scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    };

    ddo.templateUrl = 'js/directives/modal-dialog.html';

    return ddo;
});
```

// js/directives/modal-dialog.html (template for the directive)

```
<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>
  <div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div>
  <div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>
    <div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>X</div>
    <div class='ng-modal-dialog-content'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

// js/main.js

```
angular.module('angstudy', ['modalDialog']);
```

The cards are been displayed normally and the modal opens, but does not display the AE values within the modal (in this case, I'm just testing the value "user", but the json has more data). If I insert just a static value, it displays...

Answer (score 0):

I would've done it by keeping the modal html in a separate file and using a separate controller and I would pass the data to the Modal controller with the resolve keyword.
But since you are using the same controller on both the templates. You can keep a separate variable called $scope.SelectedCard to achieve the functionality.
In your toggleModal method you can assign the card as:

```
$scope.toggleModal = function(card) {
    $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
    $scope.selectedCard = card;
};
```

and in the modal you can change to:

```
<my-modal show='modalShown' width='250px' height='40%'>
    <h3>{{selectedCard.user}}</h3> <-- problem solved
</my-modal>
```

Comment: I am using the separate file to modal, just the "directive tag" is in the same html (if I understood right what you mean). I updated the post including this portion of html... And sorry, but the problem keeps. Maybe to do the separate controller to modal would be the solution.